# How do I clear a specific cache entry?

Tags: 7, drush, caching

I saved a cache entry using `cache_set()`. How can I clear this entry using Drush?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create [a custom drush command](https://www.addwebsolution.com/blog/create-custom-drush-command-in-drupal) to call the [cache_clear_all](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21cache.inc/function/cache_clear_all/7.x) function or just use:

```
drush ev "cache_clear_all('my_module', 'cache', TRUE);"
```

You can read more about cache_clear_all in [A Beginner's Guide to Caching Data in Drupal 7](https://www.lullabot.com/articles/a-beginners-guide-to-caching-data-in-drupal-7)